# Family of formulas for which Gabbay's separation algorithm explodes nonelementarily

Tags: lo.logic, temporal-logic, linear-temporal-logic

It is repeated throughout the literature that Gabbay's algorithm for
separation of LTL with Since and Until can produce nonelementary blow-up
of the size of the formula, but I have never seen a proof of this.

I'm looking for a family of formulas that exhibits this nonelementary blow-up. Or some other proof of this.